# Python3 function- return strange values

Tags: python, function

I'm learning python on singpath. 
And I trying to difficulty hard.

Anyways, I have to return values str,float,int.

I succeed almost question but I can't solve only 2 questions.

these:

```
>>>str_int('hi',2)  
   hihi 
>>>str_int(3,'bye') 
   byebyebye
```

but in my case:

```
>>>str_int('hi',2)
   hi2
>>>str_int(3,'bye')
   3bye
```

I can't understand why my code return that values without error.

this is my code:

```
def str_int(a,b):
if type(a) == type(b):
    return a+b
elif type(a) or type(b) == str:
    if type(a) and type(b) == float:
        return a+b
    elif type(a) or type(b) == float:
        return str(a)+str(b)
    return a*b
```

Comment: Also, use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `if type(a) or type(b) == str` is not equivalent to `if type(a) == str or type(b) == str`, which is probably what you really meant...